# Как программно получить размер view в BaseAdapter?

Tags: android, view

Пробовал искользовать `ViewTreeObserver` в `getView`. Но получаю 0 т.к. `view` еще не сформирована, а только заполняется. Мне надо знать размер перед тем как отобразить `view`, чтобы внести изменения. Или хотябы при уже выведенном на экранн `view` быстро сделать изменения без участия пользователя(не нажимая кнопку).

```
@Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final ViewHolder viewHolder;
        if (mData.get(position).mTemplateId == DYNAMIC_CARD){
            if (convertView == null) {
                convertView = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.card_tipe_3, parent, false);
                viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
                viewHolder.imageViewLogo = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageViewLogoUrl_1);
                viewHolder.textCompanyName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textViewCompanyName_1);
                viewHolder.textFullName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textViewFullName_1);
                viewHolder.textViewJobTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textViewJobTitle_1);
                viewHolder.textViewDepartment = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textViewDepartment_1);
                viewHolder.textViewSite = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textViewURLSite_1);
                viewHolder.textViewEmail = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textViewEmail_1);
                viewHolder.textViewAddress = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textViewAdress_1);
                viewHolder.layout = (LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.telephone_1);
                convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
            } else {
                viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }

            final ArrayList<String> phones_mPrimary = new ArrayList<>();
            phones_mPrimary.addAll(mData.get(position).mContact.mPrimary.getPhoneOffice());
            phones_mPrimary.addAll(mData.get(position).mContact.mPrimary.getPhoneDesk());
            phones_mPrimary.addAll(mData.get(position).mContact.mPrimary.getPhoneMobile());
            phones_mPrimary.addAll(mData.get(position).mContact.mPrimary.getPhoneFax());

            viewHolder.imageViewLogo.setImageURI(Uri.parse(mData.get(position).mContact.mPrimary.getImageUrl()));
            viewHolder.textCompanyName.setText(mData.get(position).mContact.mPrimary.getOrganization());
            viewHolder.textFullName.setText(mData.get(position).mContact.mPrimary.getFullName());
            viewHolder.textViewJobTitle.setText(mData.get(position).mContact.mPrimary.getJobTitle());
            viewHolder.textViewDepartment.setText(mData.get(position).mContact.mPrimary.getDepartment());
            viewHolder.textViewSite.setText(mData.get(position).mContact.mPrimary.getURL().get(0));
            viewHolder.textViewEmail.setText(mData.get(position).mContact.mPrimary.getEmail().get(0));
            viewHolder.textViewAddress.setText(mData.get(position).mContact.mPrimary.getAddress().get(0));


            //вариант 1
            viewHolder.layout.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
                @SuppressLint("NewApi")
                @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
                @Override
                public void onGlobalLayout() {
                    //now we can retrieve the width and height
                    viewHolder.layout.getHeight();
                    Log.d("MyLog", "getViewTreeObserver(). Size: " + viewHolder.layout.getHeight());
                    for (int i = 0; i < phones_mPrimary.size(); i++) {
                        TextView textView = new TextView(getActivity());
                        textView.setText(phones_mPrimary.get(i));
                        textView.setTextSize(14);
                        viewHolder.layout.addView(textView);
                    }
                }
            });
            //вариант 2
            viewHolder.layout.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    viewHolder.layout.getHeight();
                    Log.d("MyLog", "new Runnable(). Size: " + viewHolder.layout.getHeight());
                    for (int i = 0; i < phones_mPrimary.size(); i++) {
                        TextView textView = new TextView(getActivity());
                        textView.setText(phones_mPrimary.get(i));
                        textView.setTextSize(14);
                        viewHolder.layout.addView(textView);

                    }
                }
            });

        }
        Log.d("MyLog", "return convertView");
        return convertView;
    }


D/MyLog: return convertView
D/MyLog: getViewTreeObserver(). Size: 526
D/MyLog: getViewTreeObserver(). Size: 526
D/MyLog: new Runnable(). Size: 526
```

Answer (score 2):

```
public View getView (int position, final View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ...
    convertView.post(new Runnable(){
        @Override
        public void run() {
            convertView.getHeight();    //высота
            convertView.getWidth();     //ширина
        }
    });
    return convertView;
}
```

З. Ы. Писал на коленке, возможны незначительные ошибки.

Comment: Пробовал. По логам сначала завершается `getView` потом `convertView.post(new Runnable())` возвращает значение. Я пробовал подожать в `getView`завершения этого потока но приложение залипает. Правда у меня не `convertView`, а один его из дочерниш `view`

Comment: @BogdanShulga  перенесите код, который должен работать с шириной и высотой `View` вовнутрь `run(){}`

Comment: Пробовал. Я заполняю `view` `textView` елемента. Кода код в нутрти, то `view` возвращается пустой. Если вы считаете, что дожно работать, то еще раз попробую. Но я вчера с этим и другими вариантами целый день провозился.

Comment: @BogdanShulga, может покажете код? Потому что у меня всегда работает такой подход.

Comment: Добавил код и в конце лог. Но `viewHolder.layout` на макете пустой. Если выпоолнять добавление `...viewHolder.layout.addView(textView)` прямо в `getView` то макет заполняется.

Comment: @BogdanShulga,  непонятно, как оно должно работать.

Comment: Интерестная штука. Из вашей конструкции я могу менять уже имеющиеся объекты. Но вот новые не добавляются :(

Answer (score 0):

Могбы вам посоветовать использовать RecyclerView, там View переиспользуются и вы только перепривязываете данные, вот тогда и можете проводить нужные вам манипуляции.